# How to use APJP with ISA Server

Tags: authentication, proxy-server, isaserver

I was unable to use APJP beside with ISA server

Entering values for **APJP_HTTP_PROXY_SERVER_ADDRESS** in the **APJP.properties** did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think ISA server uses NTLM or KERBEROS authentication.

APJP (JAVA 6) supports BASIC, DIGEST, NTLM and KERBEROS authentication ( http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/http-auth.html )

EXAMPLE: APJP + NTLM authentication:

```
APJP_HTTP_PROXY_SERVER_ADDRESS=<ADDRESS>
APJP_HTTP_PROXY_SERVER_PORT=<PORT>
APJP_HTTP_PROXY_SERVER_USERNAME=<DOMAIN>\<USERNAME>
APJP_HTTP_PROXY_SERVER_PASSWORD=<PASSWORD>
```

Comment: ISA server uses NTLM authentication.  
It was an unknown error on my PC.
After hours of try, I did reboot the PC and now everything is fine.